# $f_n\rightarrow f $ in measure if and only if $f_n\rightarrow f$ almost uniformly in specified measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu(E)=\sum_{n\in E}n^{-2}$.

How to show that:

$f_n\rightarrow f $ in measure if and only if $f_n\rightarrow f$ almost uniformly

could you please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that $\mu$ is meant to be the measure on $\mathbb R$ which gives a 'weight' of $1/n^2$ to each integer point. 
Since $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} n^{-2} < \infty$, this is a finite measure space, and so your question follows from [Egorov's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem).
A proof of this theorem can be found at the link above or in various real analysis texts e.g. it is Theorem 2.33 in Folland's *Real Analysis*.